# Click button in a table on a specific row in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I have a page with a table and few rows where some rows have same texts as the other rows.

I want to click on a button "**Delete**" if text on the same row contains the text "**real**" in `<td class="user_type">`real
.

```
<tr id="5gf5h5gh4rthhgh1" data-id="1418753">
    <td class="website">www.123.com</td>
    <td class="user_type">real</td>
    <td class="ip_address">123.123.1.1 ()</td>
    <td class="actions">
        <div class="list-action">   
            <button class="btn default check check green markAsChecked" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-check green markAsChecked"></i>Delete</button></div></td>
</tr>

<tr id="5gf5h5gh4g5j1gh4" data-id="1418753">
    <td class="website">www.123.com</td>
    <td class="user_type">virtual</td>
    <td class="ip_address">88.123.2.2 ()</td>
    <td class="actions">
        <div class="list-action">   
            <button class="btn default check check green markAsChecked" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-check green markAsChecked"></i>Delete</button></div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Delete** when the same row contains the text **real** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *following-sibling* with class attribute:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='user_type' and text()='real']//following-sibling::td[@class='actions']//button[contains(., 'Delete')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *following-sibling* with index:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='user_type' and text()='real']//following-sibling::td[2]//button[contains(., 'Delete')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: You need to use this line of code where you want to click on a button **Delete** adding the required imports. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following xpath:

```
//tr//td[@class="user_type" and text()="real"]//following-sibling::td//button[text()="Delete"]
```